# Forwarding arguments in non-variadic "normal" functions

Tags: c++

I find myself having to write a lot of wrapper functions for things like PIMPL... i.e.:

```
Runner::Runner(int a, int b, int c) {
  handle_ = make_shared<impl>(a, b, c);
}
```

Where arguments are really intended to be directly forwarded to a lower level function.

Is there a way to do this in C++ without having to do this typing?

I guess I want std::forward, but that only works with variadic template functions per my understanding.

Comment: I am too lazy to type that also... I want something like std::forward...

Comment: @WilderField `std::forward` has nothing to do with template parameter packs, the `...` does.  You can `std::forward` non-pack arguments, but you have to write them out individually (and `std::forward` is not appropriate here, since the arguments aren't forwarding references).

Comment: @MilesBudnek so if the constructor was taking a,b, and c by reference, I could use std::forward in passing them to make_shared, given the implementation class also takes items by reference?

Comment: @WilderField If it accepted them by [_forwarding reference_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references), yes, but you would need something like `make_share<impl>(std::forward<T1>(a), std::forward<T2>(b), std::forward<T3>(c))`.  `std::forward` is just for preserving _value category_.  It has nothing to do with expanding parameter packs.

Comment: You **only** use forward where your function parameters have the form of `T&&` where `T` is a template parameter.  Otherwise you use `move` to force a move or just allows a copy to happen.  For built in types, e.g. `int`, moving and copying does the same thing.  moving only gives you a benefit with type like `std::vector` that have a pointer to the actual data they hold.

Comment: Code is written once and read many times. Everyone who reads your code will thank you for writing that `(int a, int b, int c)`. Even more so if you name those variables something that makes sense for the underlying API. It saves them from having to explore the rabbit hole that is code documentation. And they'll be *especially* grateful when they call the function with a bad argument and get a nice error message that says "expected `int` got `std::string`", rather than one that says "error in expansion `std::forward<Ts...>::my_type::validator::true_type<arg_type_t...>::value` does not exist"

Comment: Thank you all for the discussion on this, has helped a lot. @SilvioMayolo makes a really good point.

Comment: A completely off-topic side note: Never assign instance members in a constructor body; that's what the initializer list is for. Initialization in constructor bodies is asking for trouble, because nothing enforces the order of initialization w.r.t. the order of destruction.

Comment: As for the question: if you're OK with keeping the constructor definition (rather than just declaration) in a header, you can make the constructor perfectly-forwarded and variadic. `template <typename ... Args> Runner(Args &&...args) : handle_{std::make_shared<impl>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)} {}`

Comment: @WilderField, why don't you write the code you'd like to be able to write?